# Titanium Alloy Binding Model Collection with Array Inside Model

Tags: binding, model, angularjs-ng-repeat, titanium, titanium-alloy

Hi all I have an Alloy model like this

```
{
  name: xxx,
  lastName: yyy,
  telephoneNumber: ["333","444","55"]
}
```

I want to bind a collection of this model to a table view but I don't know how to bind telephoneNumber's array.
I want to have a label for each number into telephoneNumber like this.

```
<Collection src="people"/>
<TableView dataCollection="people">
  <TableViewRow>
    <View layout="vertical">
     <Label text="{name}"></Label>
     <View ng-repeat="number in people.telephoneNumber">
      <Label text="{number}"></Label>
     </View>
    </View>
  </TableViewRow>
</TableView>
```

My question is, does exists something like angular ng-repeat for titanium alloy?

Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is `dataTransform` function.

```
<TableView dataCollection="people" dataTransform="transformModel">
```

Then in your controller:

```
function transformModel(model){
    var data = model.toJSON();
    data.firstNumber = data.telephoneNumber[0];
    return data;
}
```

Then you can use the property `firstNumber` in your alloy view and display it properly.

You can read more about `dataTransform` at the [docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Data_Binding)